# Displaying the Star Wars Super Star Destroyer in a small apartment?

Tags: star-wars

It has been several years since I played with LEGOs.

Three weeks before the holidays I got the LEGO Star Wars set [10221 Super Star Destroyer](http://starwars.lego.com/en-us/Products/10221.aspx) as an impulse purchase at a local sale. Now I am stuck with a 125 centimeter, 3.5 kilogram LEGO figure.

Has anyone got any suggestions or tips on what to do with such a huge display figure in a relatively small apartment? I really should have planned this a bit better before completing it.

I have considered hanging it from the high ceiling, but I am afraid the construction is not strong enough to prevent it from falling apart. Not that it would look particularly good from the underside either.

Comment: Hummm... take a picture, frame & display it, and disassemble the kit :-) (and if you can't even store the pile of parts as itself, send it to me or something)

Comment: Seriously, isn't this an awesome problem to have?

Answer (score 14):

By using two TV wall mounts, you could put it against the wall on its side.

[image]

This guy was able to do with the LEGO Millennium Falcon(Ultimate Collector [10179](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10179-1)).  Here's a [link](http://www.brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi?f=485809) to some pictures that shows how he interfaced the TV mount with the LEGO bricks.  You will have to make some modifications to the kit but that's a good reason why LEGO are fun.

Comment: Very neat idea, beats a picture :-/

Comment: It must be very impressive in person

Comment: that's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 6):

One of my friends who had a similar issue with the LEGO Millennium Falcon (10179) beastie, got a custom coffee table built for it, it has a toughened glass top, and glass side panels, to show off it's true beauty (I believe the next step is to hook it up with some strip LED lighting too).

I don't know how feasible that would be for the SSD, I don't know the size differences between it and the MF, but it's something you could do too :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a tv holder to attach it to the wall or ceiling. 3 kg should be no problem. If this would be like a movable arm you could easily set views from any perspective.

***EDIT***

I mean something like this

[image: a tv holder with an arm]

or this one

[image]

The latter can carry up to 17.5 lbs which is 8 kilograms.